# What is the replacement for `check_compiler_abi_compatibility`?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I wanted to use an older open-source project on GitHub that hasn't been updated for  4-5 years. I encountered an issue in a section related to setup:

```py
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import \
     CUDAExtension, \
     _join_cuda_home, \
     _is_cuda_file, \
     check_compiler_abi_compatibility
```

It tells me that `check_compiler_abi_compatibility` doesn't exist in `torch.utils.cpp_extension`. Is the problem related to the version?

In the prerequisites section of the repo, it lists:

- Linux
- Python  3.7
- PyTorch v1.0.1

I brought the project to Google Colab and ran into the same problem. I installed Ninja too. I also tried updating PyTorch, but I still got the same error.

I attempted to install version  1.0.1 using pip, but it didn't install and gave me a limited list of versions that can be installed. I'm not sure if it's because of the Python version!?

I also tried installing this version with conda, but it said it wasn't available on the website. I thought maybe I need to install a lower version of Python and CUDA on Linux. Can you help me? Thank you.

Because I am more comfortable with colab I want to know is there a replacement for this function ? I tried to remove it respectfully but I encountered an error.

Also the repository link is:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/music-translation

The setup link from the repository is:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/music-translation/blob/main/src/nv-wavenet/setup.py

I will be thankful for your help.

Comment: Tangental, but it looks/looked like this https://mmcv.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.3/_modules/torch/utils/cpp_extension.html